# ORACLE XML : save XML char to CLOB, is it safe?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, clob

Halo, recently im working with xml and insert into oracle table with pl/sql, what i've did is i convert whole of xml char into clob, is it ok? the xml data contain about 200.000 of row nodes

thx for the anwers and advice :)

Comment: I don't know how you define ok.   Unless you are just making a temporary archive, this looks like a poor choice to me.  There are datatypes to support XML.  XMLType is a good choice.

Comment: Yes, it's "safe" (depending on your definition of "safe"). But it's a poor choice if you're going to to process the XML in an xmlish-way in database. Instead use `XMLTYPE`. See e.g. [Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/toc.htm) for the details. SO is also full of [Oracle+XML](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+xml) and `XMLTYPE` related questions (In fact you have posted a few by yourself).

Comment: It is OK while you are planing only to store that data. But if you need to work with that data (moving through its nodes, e t.c.) - you should look to XMLType.